# How do I fix my "self-deleting" .exe from deleting itself early?

Tags: c++, python, windows-xp, alternate-data-stream

For the sake of testing and personal proof of concept, I have a .exe file that only outputs a simple string and then calls a system pause (literally `system("pause")` in C++).

I have a simple Python script I'm testing on a Windows XP VM that does these operations when messing up:

```
subprocess.call(r'echo Nothing special. > c:\blank.txt', shell=True)
subprocess.call(r'type pause.exe > c:\blank.txt:ads.exe', shell=True)
subprocess.call(r'start c:\blank.txt:ads.exe', shell=True)
subprocess.call(r'del c:\blank.txt', shell=True)
```

Obviously, those commands all work fine alone on the command line, why don't they work fine when called through Python?

I receive this pop-up error message:

> blank.txt:ads.exe has encountered a
>   problem and needs to close. We are
>   sorry for the inconvenience.
>
> If you were in the middle of
>   something, the information you were
>   working on might be lost.

The file is indeed deleted, also. It seems that the system pause is just crushed by the delete command, when I expect the .exe to pop up, wait for me to push enter, and then the script will continue and delete the file.

Comment: I don't understand. What's the problem that you're having?

Comment: Wow, I forgot the most important part.

Comment: Maybe Windows hates you(r code)? :|

Comment: What's the concept for which this is a proof?

Comment: I'm confused by the second and third lines.  What does `:ads.exe` mean?  I'm not familiar with that syntax.

Comment: @Adrian: He's hiding the exe as an Alternate Data Stream of the text file.

Comment: @josmh: My edit before the weekend was working for a GUI exe, but not a console exe. No changes in Python would wait properly. The `start` command has a `/wait` option that works. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the symptoms, my understanding is that you can only safely delete an executable in this particular setting (Windows XP, perhaps at a particular patch level, when the executable is from an alternate stream) once this executable has finished initializing. If you delete an executable while it's loading, the program crashes.

When you type these commands at a prompt, some time elapses between running `start c:\blank.txt:ads.exe` and `del c:\blank.txt`, giving the program enough time to finish loading. When you're running them from a script, the interval between the two is a lot shorter (`start` branches off a new process, and the new program's initialization happens asynchronously). There's race condition between the initialization and the deletion; which one wins depends on how soon the deletion is performed.

Try experimenting with a delay before deleting the file:

```
import subprocess, time
subprocess.call(r'echo Nothing special. > c:\blank.txt', shell=True)
subprocess.call(r'type pause.exe > c:\blank.txt:ads.exe', shell=True)
subprocess.call(r'start c:\blank.txt:ads.exe', shell=True)
time.sleep(42)  # 42 seconds is overkill, but the delay isn't predictable
subprocess.call(r'del c:\blank.txt', shell=True)
```

Comment: Do you know a way to add a "time buffer" between the `start` and the `del`?

Comment: @josmh: In Python, [`time.sleep(NUMBER_OF_SECONDS)`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep) (after `import time`, of course).

Comment: if you add the last two lines of my code into your answer and then throw a time.sleep(3) in between, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that each `subprocess.call(..., shell=True)` is immediately returning because they're just telling the shell to execute a command. On the commandline, calling an exe to run using the `start` command will still immediately return even though the exe has not terminated. The `start` immediately returned and it needs to be told to wait:

```
subprocess.call(r'echo Nothing special. > c:\blank.txt', shell=True)
subprocess.call(r'type pause.exe > c:\blank.txt:ads.exe', shell=True)
subprocess.call(r'start /wait c:\blank.txt:ads.exe', shell=True)
subprocess.call(r'del c:\blank.txt', shell=True)
```

Comment: The documentation for subprocess.call: "Run command with arguments. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute." So I don't think that's it.

Comment: @Mu: Right. I found a question elsewhere on SO that suggested using `call()` in order to have it wait.

Comment: @Xeo The problem with agreeing with Joel at the present is that he is saying his "idea of what's going on is [getting] foggier". LOL ;)

Comment: @josmh: The edit wasn't there at the moment I made the comment. :)

Comment: I'm going to try and recreate this situation.

Comment: Your current edit is why I'm using a Windows XP VM. And as stated at the top.. this is for legitimate testing purposes. You gotta be able to make security concerns if you're going to stop them.

Comment: @Joel `subprocess.call(r'start c:\blank.txt:ads.exe', shell=False)` will newer work, should be at least `subprocess.call(['start', r'c:\blank.txt:ads.exe'], shell=False)`.
`

Answer (score 0):

The windows shell `start` command will launch the program in a new shell and then just continue. To wait for it to complete use `call`:

```
subprocess.call(r'call c:\blank.txt:ads.exe', shell=True)
```

Comment: `call` works to execute the program however when I just edited in that code and ran it, the pause still seemed to be "pushed" out of the way and the file was deleted. I don't get it.

Comment: Also, it appears "call" has problems with the extra colon in some set-ups.